# Adding additional data to select query result

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I am fetching data from Articles table but I want to extend returned result with some data from another table. 
For example:

```
public function getArticlesByCategoryId($category_id = 0) { 
    $select = $this->_db->select()
            ->from($this->_name)
            ->limit(5)
            ->order("pubDate DESC");

    $result = $this->_db->fetchAll($select);

    $mCategories = new Model_Categories();

    foreach($result as $row) { // as &$row doesn't work
        $category_name = $mCategories->getNameById($row["category_id"]);
        $row["category_name"] = $category_name; // this to add to $result but dunno how 
        // blah blah...
    } 

    return $result; // the new one with ...->category_name in it.
}
```

I hope you could understand what I am looking for. 
Or maybe it is better to write a single query (with joins, don't know how) and fetch all the data needed in once without calling methods from another Models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed looks like you should use a `join`. This definitely is the easiest way to solve your problem. The following query would do the trick:

```
$select = $this->_db->select()
        ->from($this->_name)
        ->join('category_table', 'category_table.id = ' . $this->_name . '.category_id', array('category_name'))
        ->limit(5)
        ->order("pubDate DESC");
```

This will add the category name to the row.

---

In case you don't want to use a join, you can add a custom field to your row by using a custom row class. This however requires a bit more work. Create the class as follows:

```
class MyApp_Model_Row_MyRow extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract 
{
     public $categoryName;
}
```

Then you should indicate in your DbTable class that you want to use this new row class:

```
class MyApp_Model_DbTable_Articles extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    ...
    protected $_rowClass = 'MyApp_Model_Row_MyRow';
}
```

You can then set the category name in a fetched row.

Comment: Only I get an error for setIntegrityCheck: Unrecognized method 'setIntegrityCheck()'. But even without it the result is correct. I think it is my fault because I am not sure if my whole Zend Application is configured correctly.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing out, my bad: `setIntegrityCheck()` should only be called when joining with a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` object. Since we call `select()` on the db-instance itself, a `Zend_Db_Select` object is created and the `setIntegrityCheck()` can be left out. Updated the answer. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To get all articles with data from your category table your query could look like:

```
    $select = $this->_db->select()
            ->from($this->_name)
            ->joinLeftUsing('category','category_id', array('category_name'))
            ->order("pubDate DESC");
```

See also: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html